# Eager loaded attributes not accessible in "where" query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to filter results from a `lands` table after eager loading it with `stage` and `project`.
`Land` --> Has One --> `Stage` and,
`Land` --> Has One --> `Project` and,
relationships defined in `Land` model and tested successfully.

This returns an output:

```
$availableLands = Land::with('stage', 'project');

dd($availableLands->stage->name); // works and returns (STAGE_NAME)
dd($availableLands->project->name); // works and returns (PROJECT_NAME)
```

But when I access these fields from `where` condition, it throws an error:

```
$availableLands = Land::with('stage', 'project');

$results = $availableLands->where('stage.name', 'ilike', '%'. $this->search . '%')->
orWhere('project.name', 'ilike', '%'. $this->search . '%')->
orWhere('lands.land_id', 'like', '%'. $this->search . '%')->
paginate(15);
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "stage"...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to access **name** field from **stage** and **project** in your **where** clause.

You need to join this tables to perform correctly your query.

For information, you can check the generated SQL of your query with **$yourQuery->dd();**

If we take your query:

```
$results = $availableLands->where('stage.name', 'ilike', '%'. $this->search. '%')
->orWhere('project.name', 'ilike', '%'. $this->search . '%')
->orWhere('lands.land_id', 'like', '%'. $this->search . '%')
->paginate(15);
```

The generated SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM "lands"
WHERE "stage"."name" ilike '%{$this->search}%'
OR "project"."name" ilike '%{$this->search}%'
OR "lands"."land_id" like '%{$this->search}%'
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

You can check that **stage** and **project** are not accessible without joining tables.

A solution can be:

```
$results = $availableLands->join('stages', 'lands.stage_id', '=', 'stages.id')
->join('projects', 'lands.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
->where('stages.name', 'ilike', '%'. $this->search . '%')
->orWhere('projects.name', 'ilike', '%'. $this->search . '%')
->orWhere('lands.land_id', 'like', '%'. $this->search . '%')
->paginate(15);
```

SQL Generated with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM "lands"
INNER JOIN "stages" ON "lands"."stage_id" = "stages"."id"
INNER JOIN "projects" ON "lands"."project_id" = "projects"."id"
WHERE "stages"."name" ilike '%{$this->search}%'
 OR "projects"."name" ilike '%{$this->search}%'
 OR "lands"."land_id" like '%{$this->search}%'
LIMIT 15 OFFSET 0
```

You can check you're now able to perform query including **stages** and **projects** table.

Comment: This is working and was my initial approach to this problem. Only thought about switching to eager loading to improve the performance of the query, since ```lands``` table has many records. I did the following snippet somewhere else in the code where I tried to access an eager-loaded attribute in ```sum()``` and thought it was also applicable with ```where()```:   ``` $payments = Land::with('payment')->get(); return $payments->sum('payment.total_paid');``` and it worked.